# Why Google Geocoding gives OVER_QUERY_LIMIT even with billing and delays between calls?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Background**

I'm in a project involving a website that, supposedly to have **200K+ users at peak load**, performs some business logic using the **latitude/longitude pairs** in a city given by users, while its UI asks them for **addresses** in that city instead, meaning that website needs to **convert the latters to the formers**, so the team decided to use the **Google Maps Geocoding with client side Javascript**.

As they think their database **won't be powerful enough** to cache the results, they decided **not to cache any**, meaning that all user inputs will **always be converted using that API**, so I'm asked to perform a load test to test its daily quota limit **with a Google API Key and billing enabled**.

**Setup**

As I know that there's also a rate limit, and OVER_QUERY_LIMIT will be thrown when either limit's hit, I've added a **1 second delay** between the Geocoding API calls, meaning that it'll be called **once per second**. I've also added a **30 second delay** when it returns OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, meaning that such failed requests will only be retried **after 30 seconds**.

My test results are as follows, however:

1. 410 consecutive successful calls -> OVER_QUERY_LIMIT -> 30 seconds delay
2. 78 consecutive successful calls -> OVER_QUERY_LIMIT -> 30 seconds delay
3. 20 consecutive successful calls -> OVER_QUERY_LIMIT -> 30 seconds delay
4. 16 consecutive successful calls -> OVER_QUERY_LIMIT -> 30 seconds delay
5. 12 consecutive successful calls -> OVER_QUERY_LIMIT -> 30 seconds delay
6. Less then 10 consecutive successful calls -> OVER_QUERY_LIMIT -> 30 seconds delay
7. Eventually it reaches a point that adding the 30 seconds delay actually decreases the throughput

I've also tested that, **without the 30 seconds delay**, upon reaching the 1st OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, the subsequent calls just **alternate between success and OVER_QUERY_LIMIT**, eventually to the point that it **alternatives between 1 success and 10+ OVER_QUERY_LIMIT**.

Besides, I've tried to increase the delay between the Geocoding API calls to **2 seconds** and that upon reaching OVER_QUERY_LIMIT to **60 seconds**, but the results are **surprisingly similar**. While I might just as well further increase those limits significantly, such increases are very likely to cause the delays to become **too long to be feasible**, so I decided not to test further.

While I can't disclose the codes calling the API, they're basically just using the **google.maps.Geocoder.geocode** function while restricting results to be **always in that city**.

While they don't mind much about the billing and I've told them that they should be prepared to switch to premium, we've also agreed that it's not worth doing so right now just to test the daily quota limit.

**Question**

I've read [Optimizing Quota Usage When Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/geocoding-strategies), [What happens if I exceed the usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?csw=1#usage_exceed), and **many similar questions on this site**, but none of them seems to be **even close to my case**, so I'd like to know why, **even with delays between API calls and billing enabled**, the actual test results are so far below even the 2500 free daily limit, let alone the 100K one with billing enabled?

If the answer were that **the load test is itself abusing the Google API**, then is there any other way to solidly verify that the Google API rate limit and daily quota limit are indeed highly reliable?

**Edit**

I forgot to mention that when I **refresh the page**, the Google API call will return 250-300 consecutive successful results before having the **same behavior** with the previous test results, but I'll only treat refreshing as the last resort.

Upon checking the traffics in the API Manager Dashboard, the Google Maps JavaScript API just has several requests(I think these are for loading the Google Map itself) and Google Maps Geocoding API has no requests at all, despite the fact that I've called Google Geocoding API via **google.maps.Geocoder.geocode** thousands of times today already.

It's **as if the API Key's not used**, but the browser returned an error message informing that no Google API Key's provided back when I didn't provide one.

As now the browser returns no error message at all, I can only think that the Google API Key should be working, while the dashboard traffic suggests the opposite. I've no idea of what's going on and any help's much appreciated.

I've used google.maps.version and it said that I'm using the 3.27.12 version.

Comment: `While I can't disclose the codes calling the API` - too bad, you might be doing it wrong

Comment: I've checked the codes and it's basically following the Google examples(except that no markers need to be drawn in my case):
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple
I wonder what could be wrong on the code side to cause initially several hundreds of consecutive successful calls, with delays between each, only to be followed by OVER_QUERY_LIMIT though.

Comment: `basically` - danger word :p

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Getting OVER_QUERY_LIMIT message when I'm not even close to any kind of rate limit, also using premium. I am spacing out EVERY message by 1 second, and after about 10 seconds it just starts alternating between success / over limit

Answer (score 0):

After several more hours of investigation and discussion with the team, I think the only feasible solution is to use **a combination of client side browser codes and server side webservice code**.

Then most of the requests will be handled on the client side, but for such requests returning OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, they'll be retried on the server side.

It's because from what I've read on the internet(especially [this one](https://www.storelocatorwidgets.com/blogpost/2044/Google_Maps_Geocoding_Strategies_and_Quotas_Explained)), the main barrier of the client side API calls are the rate limit, while that of the server side API calls are the daily limit.

Under the aforementioned combination, the daily limit will be mostly mitigated by the client side API calls, while the rate limit will be mostly mitigated by the server side API calls, meaning that **they're effectively covering each others' limitations**.

Nevertheless, I still wonder if there are **even better ways** that actually address the root causes rather than trying to avoid the issue while significantly complicating things.

Comment: After reading that article you linked, I think I will go with the same approach. 

It seems to indicate that there's 2 types of rate limiting for client-side. You've got rate-limiting per api key (i.e. 2500 requests/day & 50/second), but then on TOP of that rate-limiting, there is additional rate-limiting per client browser, which is not mentioned in google's docs, which is how you end up with that graph in the article which shows that approximately the first 5-10 requests are not really rate limited, and then there is exponential limiting after that starting at about 1 request / second.

Answer (score -1):

I had been hitting OVER_QUERY_LIMIT and even after resetting it to higher number, the error still persisted. Then I realised that I have multiple quotas, even though I am using single method of geocode api. Quotas are listed in Google Quotas overview in the way that one would need to scroll down to see there are more of them.

Silly, but hey, might save someone some time.